# Python Packaging multiple subpackages with different data directories

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, packaging, python-packaging

I have a structure of the directory as such with `foobar` and `alphabet` data directories together with the code `something.py`:

```
\mylibrary
    \packages
         \foobar
             foo.zip
             bar.zip
         \alphabet
             abc.zip
             xyz.zip
          something.py
     setup.py
```

And the goal is such that users can pip install the module as such:

```
pip install mylibrary[alphabet]
```

And that'll only include the data from the `packages/alphabet/*` data and the python code. Similar behavior should be available for `pip install mylibrary[foobar]`.

If the user installs without the specification:

```
pip install mylibrary
```

Then it'll include all the data directories under `packages/`.

Currently, I've tried writing the `setup.py` with Python3.5 as such:

```
import glob
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
  name = 'mylibrary',
  packages = ['packages'],
  package_data={'packages':glob.glob('packages' + '/**/*.txt', recursive=True)},
)
```

That will create a distribution with all the data directories when users do `pip install mylibrary`.

**How should I change the `setup.py` such that specific pip installs like `pip install mylibrary[alphabet]` is possible?**

Comment: Thing is, `setup.py` will never know whether the package is being installed plain or with extras. This information is being consumed by install tools (like `pip` or `easy_install`) only and is never passed to the setup script. The `extras` you define in setup script is, roughly spoken, only an additional instruction for the installer: "if you get extras keywords, you should install the package plus a bundle of additional packages", that's just it.

Answer (score 0):

Firs you have to package and publish `alphabet` and `foobar` as a separate packages as `pip install mylibrary[alphabet]` means

```
pip install mylibrary
pip install alphabet
```

After that add `alphabet` and `foobar` as `extras`:

```
setup(
    …,
    extras = {
        'alphabet': ['alphabet'],
        'foobar': ['foobar'],
    }
)
```

The keys in the dictionary are the names used in `pip install mylibrary[EXTRA_NAME]`, the values are a list of package names that will be installed from PyPI.

PS. And no, you cannot use extras to install some data files that are not available as packages from PyPI.