# Python packaging of weakly dependent projects

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools, packaging, python-packaging

I am trying to figure out a good way to package and deploy a number of python packages I created. Eventually, I would like to use some package repository for deployment or create some sort of setup script.

The structure of my project is as follows: I have two subprojects `A` and `B` that both use tools from another self-created package `C`. The tools in `C` are for internal use only and not of bigger interest to a general audience. However, `A` and `B` shall be deployed. I want that users can install `A` and `B` independently of each other, but I do not need/want to deploy `C` as standalone.

In the best case, I would like users to be able to install the packages with something along the lines of

```
pip install my_project.A
```

or

```
pip install my_project.B
```

Furthermore, in `A`, I would like to import `C` as follows:

```
import my_project.C
```

Would I have to package `A`, `B`, and `C` independently and work with `install_requires` in `setuptools.setup`? If all projects belong to a large "meta-project", is there a way I can bundle them together weakly while maintaining their general independence? (In my example, `C` contains "tools". I do not want to deploy a package with such a generic name. Would I then have to deploy it as `my_project_tools`?)

Is there a way so that all packages installed from that meta-package are installed in the same folder hierarchy while allowing the installation of separate components of that meta-package?
There is a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898504/python-packaging-multiple-subpackages-with-different-data-directories), but my problem differs in that there is the common dependency `C`.

I am new to packaging, so I appreciate answers that do not suppose too much background knowlege.

**Additional info:** I am using Python 3.7, and the program is not compatible with lower versions. It should run platform independently, though. Some modules require compilation and Cython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following could be a solution, in which *Nmspc* could be considered the *meta-project* of *Ping* and *Pong*. It's not actually tested, so some tweaking will be needed.

The directory tree might look like this:

```
.
├── NmspcCore
│   ├── nmspc
│   │   └── _core
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── common.py
│   └── setup.py
├── NmspcPing
│   ├── nmspc
│   │   └── ping
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── foo.py
│   └── setup.py
└── NmspcPong
    ├── nmspc
    │   └── pong
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── bar.py
    └── setup.py
```

3 Python projects:

- *NmspcCore* provides `nmspc._core` (the leading underscore denotes a private element) and should not be installed directly
- *NmspcPing* provides `nmspc.ping` and depends on *NmspcCore*
- *NmspcPong* provides `nmspc.pong` and depends on *NmspcCore*

They all make use of *namespace packages*. They can be designed according to the instructions from the [Python Packaging User Guide on "Packaging namespace packages, Native namespace packages"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages). There is another example [here](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/tree/master/native).

`NmspcCore/setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='NmspcCore',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=['nmspc._core',],
)
```

`NmspcCore/nmspc/_core/common.py`

```
MARCO = 'polo'
```

`NmspcPing/setup.py` (and similarly `NmspcPong/setup.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='NmspcPing',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=['nmspc.ping',],
    install_requires=['NmspcCore',],
)
```

`NmspcPing/nmspc/ping/foo.py`

```
import nmspc._core

print(nmspc._core.common.MARCO)
```

An *umbrella* project *Nmspc* could also be considered. Such a project would be empty (no actual code), but would have *NmspcPing* and *NmspcPong* as direct dependencies, so that one could install the whole projects ensemble all at once.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer! I am not sure I fully understand the underscore issue, though. Wat is the benefit of making `_core` private? Could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: 1. The leading underscore is just a Python convention. This basically means "for internal use only". When one sees the underscore, they should know not to mess with this, they should for example not import it. But remember that it is just a convention, the underscore has no actual effect and the elements are still importable. 2. The phrasing is probably misleading: the project can and will be installed but there is no point in installing it independently since it is meant as a library for internal use.

Comment: You might also want to consider an _umbrella_ project _Nmspc_ that would be empty (no actual code), but that would have _NmspcPing_ and _NmspcPong_ as direct dependencies, so that one could install the whole project all at once.